# CodeIgniter don't route to the right module

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a problem with CodeIgniter. I have created module named "user" in a subdirectory "mycompagny/dev" in my local server.

But when I want to access to my module : mycompagny/dev/**user**/login

my server is looking on mycompagny/dev/**user.txt**/login

Is someone know why I have that and how I can fix this trouble ?

[image: CodeIgniter problem]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chatis you have to add more details. Show us your controller where proper action is placed. Also tell me which CI version are you using?
Are you sure that URL should be like `/xxx/dev/user/login`? In the CI URL's routes used to be like `host.com/controller_name/action_name`.

Comment: You are right.. I have just add a hostname on my local apache server with all of subdirectory and all works fine now..